# how to install an older version of a pecl package

Tags: php, mac-osx, mongodb, pecl, pear

I have this code

```
    $passengerId = new \MongoId(oPassenger->getId());

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('Device')
        ->update()
        ->multiple(true)
        ->field('activated')->set(false)
        ->field('passenger')->unsetField()->equals($passengerId)
        ->field('_id')->notEqual($deviceId)
        ->getQuery()
        ->execute();
```

which works just fine on my dev server but crashes on my local machine.

running `pecl list` on dev returns

```
APC     3.1.13  beta
amqp    1.2.0   stable
intl    3.0.0   stable
mongo   1.3.7   stable
```

and on local returns:

```
mongo   1.5.6   stable
xdebug  2.2.5   stable
```

the crash message on my machine is

```
"name":"MongoException","message":"Invalid object ID"},"code":500}
```

I'v tried downgrading my local version of mongo but i couldn't figure it out with pecl's poor documentation. for example i tried this:

```
sudo pecl upgrade -f -c channel://pecl.php.net/mongo-1.3.7
```

but i keep on getting `channel does not exist` for all my channel permutations.

also running `mongod --version` locally returns **db version v2.6.0** and on dev returns **db version v2.4.3**

ideas?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

To downgrade, you can try this:

```
pecl install mongo-1.3.7
```

Then pecl list will show you that it worked.

Comment: One may need to force: `pecl install -f mongo-1.3.7`

Comment: Or just `pecl uninstall mongo` then `pecl install mongo-1.3.7`